# Using ng-repeat on nested array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my JSON object and I am trying to show the same in html table.

```
$scope.results = {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Sam",
      "details": [
        {
          "official": [
            {
              "address1": "Link road",
              "pincode": 76755554
            },
            {
              "address1": "K main road",
              "pincode": 9766565
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "John",
          "details": [
            {
              "official": [
                {
                  "address1": "Old college road",
                  "pincode": 11111
                },
                {
                  "address1": "near east side",
                  "pincode": 6555446
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used ng-repeat to achieve the below output. But I am not getting the expected result
[image: Final output table]

This is the code which I have tried and got stuck [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/052Lg78k/)

Any idea on how to achieve my expected result will be really helpful.

Comment: The people objects you want to iterate are at different levels of the provided `JSON` tree.

Comment: The issue I see on the JSFiddle is that the HTML table won't render the way you want it as it is currently. I am trying to think of an elegant way to make it work, but I'm not sure I can think of way to do it with a table.
EDIT: I can't think of any way to make this work easily other than a flex-box layout

Comment: @scales oh! It would have been easier if i can do the same with table. can you provide me any example

Comment: I would suggest reformatting your data if possible, either in the back end or the front end if you don't have access to the back end.

Comment: it will be much easier if you could change your data structure. Any way I would recommend to use the rowspan attribute instead nested tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to tweak this slightly if your data structure can get more complicated when there are more levels, but this should reformat your data and flatten everything into an array of people without all the different levels.

```
$scope.peopleFlat = [];

function flattenPeople(people) {
    people.forEach((person) => {
        $scope.peopleFlat.push({
           name: person.name,
           addresses: person.details[0].official
        });

        if (person.details.length > 1) {
            flattenPeople([person.details[1]]);
        }
    });
}

flattenPeople($scope.people);
```

Then you can use a combination of `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to make it work using `rowspan` instead of a nested `<table>` element.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Pincode</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="person in peopleFlat">
        <td rowspan="{{person.addresses.length || 1}}">{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.addresses.length ? person.addresses[0].address1 : ''}}</td>
        <td>{{person.addresses.length ? person.addresses[0].pincode : ''}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="address in person.addresses.slice(1)">
        <td>{{address.address1}}</td>
        <td>{{address.pincode}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```